# Scala or Java Json Schema Parser/loader from URI

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, jsonschema

I want to read some json schema files from AWS S3 and convert them to Spark StructType. Some of them have refs for other json schema files, so I can reuse them. Is there any lib in scala or java that I can use to load a merged schema that combines all the json schema files and convert them to the StructType json format?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using any JSON library just by using Spark:

```
import spark.implicits._

val logData = spark.read.json(logFile)
logData.select("city", "street", "place").as[Row]
```

But if you need to use a JSON library to model your data, you can use `spray-json`, and when you want to convert the `spray` object to Spark struct, you can convert spray object to simple string and pass it to Spark as a JSON input like this:

```
import spark.implicits._

val rawJsonString = sprayModel.toJson.compactPrint
val otherPeopleDataset = spark.createDataset(
  rawJsonString :: Nil)
val otherPeople = spark.read.json(otherPeopleDataset)
```

To see how `spray-json` will work in Scala you can see the GitHub page:

https://github.com/spray/spray-json

Hope it helps!

Comment: I need to use the spark.read, but with the schema that I already have in json schema format saved on my S3 bucket. To use this schema I will need to load it from the S3 uri and convert to StructType so I can use with Spark. I found some libs to load the schema and convert it, but they do not work with multiple json schema files based on the refs I have on the main schema file. Thats is the problem I am facing.